# Is there any simpler proof for the elementary geometric problem?

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, alternative-proof

The elementary geometric prolbem is as below:

[image]

The length of $DE$ can be calculated to be exactly 7.

But the calculation is a little complicated with many steps via trigonometry and so on.

Is there any simpler method to prove that $DE=7$?

**update**

> The method I am using, is mainly based on trigonometry, and polynomial
>   system calculation.
>
> For example,
>
> first set up a Descartes coordinate system with origin at $D$, with
>   $\vec{DA}$ as vertical and $\vec{DC}$ as horizontal axes;
>
> then all coordinates of points $A, B, C$ can be easily obtained;
>
> In order to obtain that of $E$, try to construct two circles as
>   indicated in the figure above, with fixed circumferential angles on
>   the specific chords; then one of the intersection points of the two
>   circles is $E$.
>
> Once coordinate of $E$ obtained, I can calculate the length of $DE$.
>
> The whole process is just easy to understand but difficult to
>   calculate. So far my calculation is based on symbolic software.

Comment: "Is there any simpler method to prove that $DE=7$?" Your question is unanswerable at the moment unless you give your solution or describe it in detail.

Comment: The method I am using, is mainly based on trigonometry, and polynomial system calculation. e.g. , it is possible to set up a Descartes coordinate system with origin at $D$, $DA$ as vertical and $DC$ as horizontal axes. then all coordinates of points $A, B, C$ can be easily obtained. In order to obtain that of $E$, try to construct two circles as indicated in the original post, one of the intersection point is $E$. Once coordinate of $E$ obtained, I can calculate the length of $DE$. Easy to unerstand, but difficult to calculate. My calculation is based on symbolic software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An algebraic approach: use the same Descartesian coordiante system as yours, then the coordinates:

$$A:(0,\dfrac{49}3),B:(-\dfrac{49}4,0),C:(\dfrac{49}4,0)$$

Let $E: (x,y)$, since $\cos\angle AED=-\dfrac{1}2$ and $\cos\angle BEC=-\dfrac{3}5$,

apply Cosine theorem to $\Delta BEC$ and $\Delta AED$ respectively so that you can obtain the following two equations:

$$\left\{
\begin{array}{rl}
 6 x^2+6 y^2-98 y+\sqrt{\left(9 x^2+(49-3 y)^2\right) \left(x^2+y^2\right)}&=0 \\
80 x^2+80 y^2+3 \sqrt{256 x^4+512 y^2 x^2-76832 x^2+256 y^4+76832 y^2+5764801}&= 12005 \\
\end{array}
\right.$$

Visualize them and solve it (you can use any symbolic software, Maxima, Axiom,  Mupad in matlab, maple, mathematica  and so on):

[image]

there are two solutions to the equations:

$$x=\pm\dfrac{5 \sqrt{3}}{2},y=\frac{11}{2}$$

Which means $E$ can locate at either of the two positions inside $\Delta ABC$.

Then $DE=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=7$